# How to use MiKTeX on MacOS Sierra?

Tags: miktex

> You can’t use this version of the application “MiKTeX Console.app”
>   with this version of macOS.
>
> You have macOS 10.12.6. The application requires macOS 10.13 or later.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really need MikTeX? There is also Mac TeX (www.tug.org/mactex) which may also suit your needs and should be compatible with the version of your OS.

Comment: Thank you! MacTex' installation file takes too long time to be downloaded.

Comment: Well, then you could install the basic installation of Mac TeX (http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) which is only 72 MB.

Comment: If the basic-one can automatically install missing packages, then I would prefer it.

Comment: @gloschtla MacTeX/BasicTeX doesn't install packages automatically. But they're easy to install with `tlmgr` or the TeXLive Utility that comes with MacTeX.  And the basic installation comes with most things most users will need.

Comment: That's why I prefer MiKTeX, because I'm not nerdy enough to use tlmgr. Now someone closed the notebook, so the download of the full-file was started all over again (because Firefox' download manager is not useful enough)

Comment: MiKTeX is availabe for High Sierra: https://miktex.org/download

Comment: Yes -- MikTeX is available for High Sierra (MacOS 10.13), but not for Sierra (MacOS 10.12), which is the OS installed on your system. Is something preventing you from updating your Mac's OS from "Sierra" to "High Sierra"? "High Sierra" has been available for download for several months by now; its current version is 10.13.3.

Comment: @gloschtla The TeX Live Utility is a regular Mac application which you can use to run `tlmgr` with no nerdiness required.